# Animate the movement of nodes of a mesh with the python API

Tags: python, scripting, animation-nodes

I am animating the vibrations on a mesh by moving the nodes through a series of positions. I have a small preliminary code for a few locations. I need to animate each location of each node with a frame. I have this not very robust code for a preliminary test.
When I try to run it, the application stops responding. How do I improve the code?

````
frame_start = bpy.context.scene.frame_start
frame_end = 4

new_position = [(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)]

while True :
    frame = frame_start
    
    while frame <= frame_end:

        for j, vertex in enumerate(mesh.vertices):
            for i, node in enumerate(new_position):
               
                original_positions = [vertex.co.copy() for vertex in mesh.vertices]
                mesh.vertices[j].select = True
           
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

                bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=node)
               
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
                              
                mesh.update()
                mesh.vertices[j].keyframe_insert(data_path='co', frame=frame)```
````

Comment: application stops responding because your code is stuck in infinite loop. you never incremented `frame` so `while frame <= frame_end` is always `True`. Use `range()` or increment `frame`. Also there is no break condition of outer `while` loop.